# How to give servers in the list of connections an alias

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2012.

When I want to connect to a server, the "Connect to Server" dialogue box appears.
In that dialogue, there's a drop down list of all the possible servers.
I have lots of different IP addresses dependant on which server I want to connect to...

Is there any way of giving these IP addresses an alias ?

eg. instead of 219.115.213.81  I could have "My test DB"

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: In SQL Server Configuration manager look for SQL Client configuration and add an Alias.

Comment: SQL Server configuration manager only seems to show my local DB, not the DB's I have listed as IP addresses in my "Connect To Server" dialogue box...

Comment: Yes it will do.  However if you add an Alias in the SQL Client configuration you will be able to connect via the alias you give it.  For example if you want to connect to 192.168.0.45 using the name Bertie set a new alias with and Alias Name of Bertie and a Server of 192.168.0.45 (don't worry about ports if you are using the defaults).  Then in SSMS you can connect to Bertie.

Comment: Fred, you've correctly answered my question - Thanks a lot !!
I can't mark it as answered because you've left a comment on my question instead of leaving an answer...

If you can leave an answer, I'll mark it correct, thank you once again !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an Alias in the SQL Client configuration you will be able to connect via the alias you give it. For example if you want to connect to 192.168.0.45 using the name Bertie set a new alias with and Alias Name of Bertie and a Server of 192.168.0.45 (don't worry about ports if you are using the defaults). Then in SSMS you can connect to Bertie

Comment: and just in case people don't read the commets above - expect this:


SQL Server configuration manager will only show your local DB, not all those listed in my "Connect To Server" dialogue box... 
However, if you add an Alias in the SQL Client configuration you will be able to connect via the alias you give it. For example if you want to connect to 192.168.0.45 using the name Bertie set a new alias with and Alias Name of Bertie and a Server of 192.168.0.45 (don't worry about ports if you are using the defaults). Then in SSMS you can connect to Bertie.